# How to manipulate chromeoptions through R language?

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, hide

I've installed `selenium-3.141.59`,chromedriver for chrome `107.0.5304.122(for 32 bit)`, `R4.2.3,Rstudio 2023.06`
I expect that the target site does not recognize that my browser is controlled by selenium.
For example,
How can I hide info bar, which pasted `Chrome is being controlled by automated testing software`

I expect that the target site does not recognize that my browser is controlled by selenium.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.